# Itertools combinations: How to get the ids of the first fitting value combination

Tags: python, pandas, list, combinations, python-itertools

I have a record with a unique ID and an associated value in EURO.
Now I want to get the first combination of values ​​that matches a value I defined.
So far I only get the combination of the values, but I would like to have the IDs of the respective values ​​also in the output.

- Actual result:

```
List->  20.5 10.0 12.0
```

- Desired result:

```
List-> 1:20.5 3:10.0 5:12.0
```

Two separated list would also be fine

Here is my first approach:

```
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# initialize list of lists
data = [[1 , 20.5], [2 , 32.0], [3 , 10.0], [4 , 5.0], [5 , 12.0], [6 , 10.0], [7, 2.0], [8 , 1.0], [9 , 6.0], [10 , 3.0], [11, 2.0]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID', 'EUR'])
summed_amount = 42.5

# Get All Possible Combinations Of Numbers In List
for value in range(1, len(df) +1):
    possible_combination = list(combinations(df['EUR'], value))
    #get the first values which equals the desired amount (summed_amount)
    li =[each for each in possible_combination if sum(each) == summed_amount]
    if li:
        print("List-> ", *li[0])
        break
```

RESULT:

```
List->  20.5 10.0 12.0
```

Thanks and kind regards :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways you can do that. You need to somehow store the values with their ids. You can do workarounds in pandas for that, or do a more elegant solution with your own custom class. Take a look:

```
class MyAmount(object):
  def __init__(self, id, value):
    self.id = id
    self.value = value

  def __radd__(self, other):
    return self.value + (other.value if isinstance(other, MyAmount) else other)
    
  def __repr__(self):
    return "{}: {}".format(self.id, self.value)
```

Here we create our own class, `MyAmount`, with our own custom logic. Then, we can just create `MyAmount` objects for each row.

```
amounts = df.apply(lambda s: MyAmount(s.ID, s.EUR), axis=1)
```

Now, just keep your code, but make sure to use `amounts` to find the combinations.

```
possible_combination = list(amounts, value))
```

Since we overrode the `__radd__` magic function, `sum(each)` will sum over the `value` property of `MyAmount`. And since we overrode `__repr__`, when you print a `MyAmount` object, you'll display a string with format `id: value`.

You can customize this however you want.

Comment: it worked but there is one problem. It seems to be not very efficient cause the dataset could have millions of entries. I've read that maybe some kind of hashing could reduce the calc. time. But i couldn't find a way to implement it in the right way @rafaelc

Comment: @JayAitschAitsch Well, you calculating _all_ combinations from `1` to `len(df)+1` of all values in the dataframe. Your approach itself is not very performant. The problem here is more about the algorithm, than about the implementation. You have to consider a different algorithm. This is actually a pretty standard problem in coding interviews, and there are some solutions to that. Right now, you are doing a brute force approach. Think of different data structures to use here. As an illustration, see https://leetcode.com/problems/target-sum/ and https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/ and expand.